# Excel Formula to count sick occurances

Tags: excel-formula

Im not sure if this is possible but....

I have an excel document with a list names in the A column, and then a list of dates in the first row. I basically want to count how many block occurances of sick are showing.

```
               Sick     01/05    02/05    03/05   04/05   06/05  07/05
Analyst Name 1          sick              sick
Analyst Name 2                            sick            sick
Analyst Name 3                                    sick
```

Above is how the table looks like. What i want in column B is to show many times a person is sick as occurances. I also want saturdays ignored, unless it shows a sick.

So Analyst 1 should show as 2 occurrences, one for 01/05, then back to work on the 02/05, then sick again on 03/05.

Analyst 2 should show as 1 occurrence, and they were sick on the 03/05, was not rota'd to work Saturday, and sick again on 06/05

And Analyst 3 should show as 1 occurrence, as they were Rota'd to work Saturday and they were sick.

I've tried researching but have only found counting those unique values, rather than counting as just one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is the formula supposed to know if the analyst was or was not "Rota'd" to work?

Comment: It would have a shift time added. Otherwise it would be blank.

Comment: Please show how the table would actually look then with the shift times added.  There is no way with the given information in the table for us to know whether it was a missed day due to sickness or not scheduled.

Comment: Not sure  I understand the problem... how does =countif(C2:H2,"sick") does not work for you? You mention wanting Saturdays to be ignored, unless it shows a "sick", but then again, you are looking to count only "sick" and don't seem to need a denominator. So you effectively want to count Saturdays...